# Display image map if no Flash detected

Tags: html

So my basic understanding was that the `<noscript>` tag was used to display content if the user has scripting disabled, especially useful when there is no flash player.

So I am trying to figure out why in some code that was sent to me, that they have an `<object>` tag inside of the `<noscript>` tag...

```
<noscript>
    <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="https://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=10,0,0,0" width="785" height="525" id="home" align="middle">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
    <param name="movie" value="home.swf" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />    <embed src="home.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="785" height="525" name="home" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="https://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>
</noscript>
```

Second part to my question is, can you put an image map in place of the flash player if scripting  or flash has been disabled...

need to put an image map with two area coords:

```
<area shape="rect" coords="175,196,372,250"> <area shape="rect" coords="417,197,616,249">
```

Comment: The `<noscript>` tag has nothing to do with whether Flash is installed / enabled or not. You will need to use something else

Answer (score 0):

The noscript element is designed to let you give alternate content (text) to users who have Javascript disabled.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Hello, world!");
        </script>
        <noscript>You have Javascript disabled.</noscript>
    </body>
</html>
```

To provide alternate content for Flash, display the Flash using an object element, then embed another object element within it that contains the picture, like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>

        <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"   
                codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab# version=6,0,40,0"
                width="800" height="600">
            <param name="movie" value="home.swf">
            <object data="somePicture.png" type="image/png"></object>
        </object> 
    </body>
</html>
```