# Button to switch between javascripts in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am using JW Player to play videos for my site, I prefer using their HTML 5 versus Flash but occasional IE or the likes won't load and it doesn't fall back to Flash super reliably. This is also all done inside of wordpress.
In the script I make the call to load either flash or html using primary: "flash" as you can see below.

```
    <div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jwplayer("myElement").setup({
            file: "http://example.com/uploads/myVideo.mp4",
            image: "http://example.com/uploads/myPoster.jpg",
            width: 640,
            height: 360,
            primary: "html"
         });
   </script>
```

What I would like to do is have a button "Can't see the video below click Here to switch to Flash" (or vice versa). I don't mind having an entirely additional script where "flash" is the only difference. But I'm not sure how to set it up correctly. I'd rather not send them to entirely new page with the alternate video player. 
Thanks! I'm diving into Javascript and PHP, I'm new but enjoying learning new things.

Comment: This should put you on your way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985976/display-image-map-if-no-flash-detected